# Rename multiple columns based on pattern search

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename

I am importing an excel file with a lot of indentation in the row values. These indentations are used to specify categories and subcategories. When I port the file to pandas, there are lot of unnamed columns created like:

> ['Levels in Millions ', **'Unnamed: 1', 'Unnamed: 2', 'Unnamed: 3'**,
>   ' ',
>          'Total National Health Expenditures', 'Hospital Care',
>          'Physician and Clinical Services', 'Other Professional Services',
>          'Dental Services', **'Unnamed: 10'**,
>          'Other Health, Residential, and Personal Care', 'Home Health Care',
>          'Nursing Care Facilities and Continuing Care Retirement Communities',
>          'Unnamed: 14', 'Prescription Drugs', 'Durable Medical Equipment',
>          'Other Non-durable Medical Products', 'Unnamed: 18', 'Unnamed: 19',
>          'State', 'Federal', 'Net Cost of Health Insurance',
>          ' Government Public Health Activities', 'Unnamed: 24', 'Research',
>          'Structures', 'Equipment']

I have tried a couple of things:

```
    type_of_prog_1.columns= type_of_prog_1.columns.str.replace('Unnamed: *', 
    '')
    type_of_prog_1= type_of_prog_1.rename(columns=lambda x: 
    x.replace('Unnamed: *', 'Level: *'))
```

The output is that the columns gets numbers as 1, 2, 3, etc. The numbered columns makes it difficult for slicing, later.

Ideally, I want the columns to be named as "Level 1" or Level 2" based on the numbers after "Unnamed". Because there are 24 Unnamed columns, I don't want to do this- {"Unnamed 1": "Level 1",...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description of the problem, you could call `Index.str.replace`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('Unnamed:', 'Level')
```